# Using React Native with Next.js

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, mobile, next.js, capacitor

I’m in the process of building a web app using Next.js for a bootcamp project. It’s a simple trip planning / packing list app, and I think it’d be really useful as a mobile app—especially since it doesn’t have too much going on. I chose Next for it because it was part of the MVP for the project.

I know there’s a lot involved—I know Swift and have Xcode. Is React Native my best bet for this? Does it work with Next? I went down a Google rabbit hole and saw an article about using Next with Capacitor and Ionic.

Does anyone have any strong opinions? A mobile app is a stretch goal for my project, so I wanted to make the best and quickest decision.